# Reducing an ansatz to a shallower circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, vqe

Given a very general hardware efficient ansatz as in Figure:

[image: Example of Hardware efficient ansatz from Scaling of variational quantum circuit depth for condensed matter systems]

and say that you already know all the rotation parameter for the gates in the red box, **is there any way to build a gate sequence that approximates the effect of those gates but requires fewer gates**?

For example, imagine that just coincidentally you could have obtained a very similar same state vector to the one obtained in the sequence in the red box just by using a few $X$ and $CNOT$, then you could "compress" that gate sequence and have it easier to run.

However, I would imagine generally speaking a shallower representation is not always possible. Is there a computationally cheap and simple mathematical procedure that allows checking if that gate sequence can somewhat be represented by a smaller gate set?

Don't hesitate to ask for clarification in the comments if necessary

Comment: Novice here, but my intuition tells me that having a lot of control gates is required to get a good degree of entanglement. I think that if you want a highly entangled state that it is required to have a lot of control gates. So unfortunately, I don't think there is a way around it.